# segue from class to swift UI Class

Tags: swift, class, swiftui, segue

I want to segue from a regular class to a swift ui class. Right now I am getting a runtime error at  let vc = ChildHostingController() "Expected member name or constructor call after type name". I dont know what to put in it I tried coder that did not work. The code works from a regular class to a regular class. I dont have a lot of experience with swiftUI.

```
import UIKit; import SwiftUI
class ViewController : UIViewController{
    
    var eee = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [eee].forEach{
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
            $0.backgroundColor = UIColor(
                red: .random(in: 0.0...1),
                green: .random(in: 0.9...1),
                blue: .random(in: 0.7...1),
                alpha: 1
            )
            
        }
        
        eee.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
        eee.addTarget(self, action: #selector(move), for: .touchDown)
    }
    
    
    @objc func move(){
        let vc = ChildHostingController(coder: <#NSCoder#>)
        vc?.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext // actually .fullScreen would be better
        self.present(vc!, animated: true)}
       
        
        
    
    }

class ChildHostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder,rootView: ContentView());
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var SelectedColor: Color = .red
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(SelectedColor)
                .frame(width: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, height: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/100/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding()
            Form{
                ColorPicker("change Color", selection: $SelectedColor)
            }
        }
        

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62416185/12299030?

Comment: A good first step would be parenthesis after ChildHostingController (let vc = ChildHostingController())

Comment: @Asperi no it did not answer my question